# Responsive text according to the containing div

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I usually use calc with vw to create responsive font-size. For example, 
`p {font-size: calc(13px + 0.33vw}}`. this usually works great, but in some cases, especially where I have responsive columns which might shrink or expand, it might be better to define the font-size relative to the containing div. I'm looking for something like: `p{font-size: 13px +2%}` when 2% is from the containing div. Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK this can only be done using JS :( (unless `body` is such parent, where in such case you'd go with `vw`)

Comment: or using an iframe inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using built-in relative CSS units like `em` or `rem`, unlike `px` values your font size becomes relative to that of its parent or that of the root element.

You can check them out here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems